# How do I force accordion to open up one at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have 2 accordions.

[image]

---

How do I force it to open up one at a time ?

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="course-summary-container">
    <!-- Append Course Summary Banner Here -->
    <div class="row" style="padding: 0px 60px;">
        <div class="panel-group " id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel course-summary ">
                <div class="panel-heading panel-0" role="tab" id="heading-0"><span class="pull-left left"><div class="panel-title h1">Course Summary</div><div class="panel-title h2" id="course-name">Advanced 1: Common Core</div></span><span class="pull-right right show-score-0 " data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse0" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse0"><div><img src="http://s6.postimg.org/ramwlv83h/report_blue.png" width="30"></div><a class="h3" role="button">VIEW REPORT</a></span><span class="pull-right right hide-score-0 hidden " data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse0" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse0"><div><img src="http://s6.postimg.org/4kipvrikd/hidedetails_blue.png" width="30"></div><a class="h3" role="button">HIDE DETAILS</a></span>
                </div>
                <!-- End Panel Heading -->
                <div id="collapse0" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-0">
                    <div class="panel-body" id="course-summary-panel-body-0">
                        <!-- Append Score Details Here -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-4 col-md-4 left"><span class="course-name">Chapter 1</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6 mid"><span class="date">08/24/2015</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 pull-right right">
                                <div class="score">0%</div>
                                <div class="h5">SCORE</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding: 0px 60px;">
        <div class="panel-group " id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel course-summary ">
                <div class="panel-heading panel-1" role="tab" id="heading-1"><span class="pull-left left"><div class="panel-title h1">Course Summary</div><div class="panel-title h2" id="course-name">Geometry: Common Core</div></span><span class="pull-right right show-score-1 " data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1"><div><img src="http://s6.postimg.org/ramwlv83h/report_blue.png" width="30"></div><a class="h3" role="button">VIEW REPORT</a></span><span class="pull-right right hide-score-1 hidden " data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1"><div><img src="http://s6.postimg.org/4kipvrikd/hidedetails_blue.png" width="30"></div><a class="h3" role="button">HIDE DETAILS</a></span>
                </div>
                <!-- End Panel Heading -->
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
                    <div class="panel-body" id="course-summary-panel-body-1">
                        <!-- Append Score Details Here -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-4 col-md-4 left"><span class="course-name">Chapter 1</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6 mid"><span class="date">08/24/2015</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 pull-right right">
                                <div class="score">0%</div>
                                <div class="h5">SCORE</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**JS**

```
$(function () {

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        var $courseSummaryHeading = $('.course-summary .panel-heading.panel-' + i);
        var $showBtn = $('.show-score-' + i);
        var $hideBtn = $('.hide-score-' + i);

        $('#collapse' + i).on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
            $hideBtn.removeClass('hidden');
            $showBtn.addClass('hidden');
            $courseSummaryHeading.css({
                'border-bottom': '8px solid #273645'
            });
        });

        $('#collapse' + i).on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
            $showBtn.removeClass('hidden');
            $hideBtn.addClass('hidden');
            $courseSummaryHeading.css({
                'border-bottom': '1px solid #273645'
            });
        });
    }





});
```

---

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/rh8wsshL/4/)

Comment: Combine the two into one or collapse **all** before opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collapse all before opening:

```
    $('#collapse' + i).on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        $('[id^=collapse]').trigger('hide.bs.collapse'); //<<<<<----
        $hideBtn.removeClass('hidden');
        $showBtn.addClass('hidden');
        $courseSummaryHeading.css({
            'border-bottom': '8px solid #273645'
        });
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/rh8wsshL/6/)

Comment: Do I need to do anything on my ` $('#collapse'+i).on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {} ?`

Comment: I do not see any need to. As you can see from my demo everything works fine with just the one line I added.

Comment: Pleasure was all mine. Feel free to vote and accept the answer if you found it useful. Enjoy :-)

Comment: I was close to do that, but , I tried click on the top, bot, and top. Both open up again :(

Comment: Do you think I should put `$('[id^=collapse]').collapse();` ?

Comment: I don't think `.collapse()` is a valid method. Let me take a look.

Comment: I've tried that. It's not working. :(, I guess, I'll research more into it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide all the div which class is `#collapse" + number"`.

Ok, following your example, you just have to hide all the divs when it is collapsed

```
$('#collapse' + i).on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('#collapse').hide(); // Added here
  $hideBtn.removeClass('hidden');
  $showBtn.addClass('hidden');
  $courseSummaryHeading.css({
      'border-bottom': '8px solid #273645'
  });
});
```

Please see the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rh8wsshL/5/) updated